# R, error when using min(diff(x)) on doubles

Tags: r, diff, min

I encountered an error that makes no sense to me.
When using `min(diff(x))` on integer numbers, no error occurs. But when using doubles, there is something wrong.

```
x <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10)
min(diff(x))
# 1
min(diff(x)) == 1
# TRUE
```

But when doing this on doubles, the following happens...

```
x <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)
min(diff(x))
# 0.1
min(diff(x)) == 0.1
# FALSE
```

Also, the result of `min(diff(x))` has the identical format as a regular double variable.

Can you reproduce this? I am using R 3.0.1

Is this error worth reporting?

Comment: If this is not reproducible, and because floating points (see first comment) are problematic sometimes, I guess this error is not worth reporting. Thanks!

Comment: It is reproducible. It's a known limitation of floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Such comparisons should be done with `all.equal`, e.g. `all.equal(min(diff(x)), 0.1)`.

Comment: @QuantIbex  `all.equal` has its little quirks.  When just comparing two scalars, as is being done here, it's safer to test `abs(x-y)<.Machine$double.eps^.5`

Comment: @Carl Witthoft would this be different from `all.equal(x, y, tol=.Machine$double.eps^.5)`?

Comment: @QuantIbex Try `all.equal(3,4)` and see what you get.

Comment: @Hong Ooi How does your example help me to determine if `abs(x-y)<.Machine$double.eps^.5` is different from `all.equal(x, y, tol=.Machine$double.eps^.5)`?

Comment: @QuantIbex Just try it and see what you get.

Comment: @QuantIbex  read the help page for `all.equal` -- if your two objects have different attributes, you will get an annoying :-)  message even if the actual numeric values are the same.

Comment: The other thing about `all.equal` is that if the values are NOT all equal, you get back a string like "hey numbskull, these numbers aren't equal!" instead of a neat, tidy `FALSE`.

Comment: @Hong Ooi The reason I dared ask you is that I did try, but didn't see your point. Or at least, I thought that your point was not the fact that the output of `all.equal` was a character when the numbers differ. I thought there was some other mystery (at least to me) due to floating points representations. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out.